# Vm goes to saved state when removing CSV

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, cluster, cluster-shared-volumes

I have a 5 node Hyper-V cluster running.

All 5 servers are running Server 2012 R2, each node is attached two devices using iSCSI. The device I'm having problems with had a single volume that was used as a CSV. This was presented to the servers under `c:\clusterstorage\volume2`

I have gone through the process of moving all VM storage on to a new device, the new CSVs are up and running and nodes are connected. Everything for the new device is working correctly.

I then tried to remove the old device as a shared storage device by doing the following. I used PowerShell to get the paths of all VHDs on the cluster and none are pointing at `c:\clusterstorage\volume2` I checked the configuration paths are not pointing at `c:\clusterstorage\volume2` I also checked that the snapshot paths are not pointing at `c:\clusterstorage\volume2`

I started removing the iSCSI target on 4 of the nodes (The 4 the storage resources was not currently 'assigned' to) and this was successful. I then went to Failover Cluster Manager and set the CSV to offline. Instantly 2 of the VMs went into a saved state (luckily not critical servers). I brought the resource back online and started the machines. I inspected the settings page for each VM and there was no reference to `c:\clusterstorage\volume2\` on either. I then went looking for the configuration files just to manually ensure something wasn't different between them and the settings page. I first looked in  `c:\clusterstorage\volume2\` the folder for either VM was not present here. I looked in the new locations `c:\clusterstorage\volume5\` and `c:\clusterstorage\volume6\` the folder for each VM was here. I checked the configuration files and they were exactly as they should be and didn't contain any reference to `c:\clusterstorage\volume2\` I checked the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Virtual Machines` where I found the shortcuts for each VM pointing at the new volume locations.

In short nothing I can find points to `c:\clusterstorage\volume2\` but if I take that CSV offline the two machines go into a saved state.

Even stranger I tried this again while writing this and yes the two machines went into a Saved State but I was able to start them again even though the CSV remained in a offline state. I now have two VMs where on the resource tab for each the storage shows as offline, but they are 'working'

So can anyone point me at a possible fix for this, perhaps a configuration file I've not found? Or would my best course of action be to delete the VMs while preserving VHDs and create a new VM and attach the original VHDs.

Sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: check your 3rd paragraph `voume2 `? need a edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience with Hyper-V in 2012 R2 but do have plenty with Hyper-V, Clusters etc. on 2008 R2 so will guess at the possible issue here.

I found that with Failover Clustering (in 2008 R2) when you add a VM into a failover cluster it will inspect the attached VHDs and the storage on which they reside and make a record of this in the **cluster** config so that they can be shown as dependent resources in Failover Cluster Manager (in the Storage pane when the VM is selected).

This does not necessarily reflect the *current* location of the VHD files - if they have been moved in Hyper-V since adding the VM to the failover cluster the dependency information is not updated. So you might have a VM that can access its disks just fine but failover clustering thinks it still has a dependency on the disk you are removing. When you offline the disk, it offlines the VM as a logical consequence. To solve (assuming this turns out to be the problem - have a look at the storage panel for the VM within FCM), remove the VM from the cluster and re-add it.

By the way as a best practice I would not generally start tearing down any iSCSI connections before you have removed the CSV from FCM.